# Update help center article on search to reflect the new position of the search box

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, top-bar, help-center

The page [/help/searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) says:

> Enter search terms in the search box that appears in the upper right corner of every page

But the box is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now reads:

> Enter search terms in the search box that appears on the center-left of the top bar on every page, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
> (On small screens, you may need to activate the search button [image: magnifying glass symbol] to show the textbox first)